# Invalid data using GPS TinyShield module with Tinyduino

Tags: gps, tinygps

I am new in GPS modules and I need to get the NMEA data from my GPS module but when I execute my code all the NMEA sentences are Invalid.

I am using the same example from instructables Tiny GPS Tracker https://www.instructables.com/Tiny-GPS-Tracker/ and it does not work. So I found other code examples and changed them a little bit.

My code is below. I have the GPS_RX wired with Arduino TX and the same logic for GPS_TX-Arduino RX and Baud is 9600, all these details are inside GPS.h.

If I change the wiring between TX and RX or gps baud the system does not work at all, so I strongly believe that these values are correct.

```
#include "GPS.h"
#include <SD.h>

#if defined (ARDUINO_ARCH_AVR)
#define SerialMonitorInterface Serial
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#elif defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD)
#define SerialMonitorInterface SerialUSB
#include "SoftwareSerialZero.h"
#endif

const int chipSelect = 10;
int cardPresent;

// The GPS connection is attached with a software serial port
SoftwareSerial softSerial(GPS_RXPin, GPS_TXPin);

#define Gps_serial softSerial

void setup()
{
  Gps_serial.begin(GPSBaud);
  SerialMonitorInterface.begin(115200);
  while (!SerialMonitorInterface && millis() < 5000); //On TinyScreen+, this will wait until the Serial Monitor is opened or until 5 seconds has passed

  gpsInitPins();
  delay(100);
  SerialMonitorInterface.print("Attempting to wake GPS module.. ");
  gpsOn();
  SerialMonitorInterface.println("done.");
  delay(200);

  //Enable and set interval or disable, per NMEA sentence type
  Gps_serial.print(gpsConfig(NMEA_GGA_SENTENCE, 0));
  Gps_serial.print(gpsConfig(NMEA_GLL_SENTENCE, 0));
  Gps_serial.print(gpsConfig(NMEA_GSA_SENTENCE, 0));
  Gps_serial.print(gpsConfig(NMEA_GSV_SENTENCE, 0));
  Gps_serial.print(gpsConfig(NMEA_RMC_SENTENCE, 1));
  Gps_serial.print(gpsConfig(NMEA_VTG_SENTENCE, 0));
  Gps_serial.print(gpsConfig(NMEA_GNS_SENTENCE, 0));

  SerialMonitorInterface.print("Initializing SD card...");

  // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
  if (SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    SerialMonitorInterface.println("card initialized.");
    cardPresent = true;
  } else {
    SerialMonitorInterface.println("Card failed, or not present- continuing with serial output");
    cardPresent = false;
  }
}

void loop() {
  handleGPS();
}

char waitForCharacter() {
  while (!Gps_serial.available());
  return Gps_serial.read();
}

void handleGPS() {
  while (Gps_serial.read() != '$') {
    if(!Gps_serial.available()){
      return;
    }
  }
  int counter = 1;
  char c = 0;
  char buffer[100];
  buffer[0] = '$';
  c = waitForCharacter();
  while (c != '*') {
    buffer[counter++] = c;
    if(c=='$'){//new start
      counter=1;
    }
    c = waitForCharacter();
  }
  buffer[counter++] = c;
  buffer[counter++] = waitForCharacter();
  buffer[counter++] = waitForCharacter();
  buffer[counter++] = '\r';
  buffer[counter++] = '\n';
  buffer[counter] = '\0';

  buffer[1] = 'G';
  buffer[2] = 'P';

  gpsDoChecksum(buffer);

  if (cardPresent) {
    File dataFile = SD.open("gps.txt", FILE_WRITE);
    // if the file is available, write to it:
    if (dataFile) {
      dataFile.write(buffer, counter);
      dataFile.close();
    } else {
      SerialMonitorInterface.println("error opening gps.txt");
      cardPresent = false;
    }
  } else {
    SerialMonitorInterface.print((char *)buffer);
  }
}
```

After I wait aprox. 30 seconds which is the cold start of the gps I still receive invalid NMEA sentences.
(I tested it outdoors and indoors)

$GPRMC,181341.901,V,,,,,,,211020,,,N*4B
$GPRMC,181342.901,V,,,,,,,211020,,,N*48
$GPRMC,181343.901,V,,,,,,,211020,,,N*49
$GPRMC,181344.901,V,,,,,,,211020,,,N*4E
$GPRMC,181345.901,V,,,,,,,211020,,,N*4F

Can someone explain to me what is going on?

Comment: V stands for invalid sentence, I can't find a way to generate valid sentences

Comment: looks like the module is not able to determine location .... maybe not enough satellites are being received .... perhaps the GPS module has a setting for sensitivity level ... maybe the antenna is bad, or badly connected ... this does not appear to be an Arduino problem .... just a note: your code is overly complicated for debugging ... all that is required, is to copy the received characters to SerialMonitor .... see the SoftwareSerial example in the Arduino IDE

Comment: I tried similar code that only prints the sentences and the validity, but all of them were invalid. I tried the same code outdoors but same results.   Could it be faulty antenna??

Comment: think about it logically ... the module is generating valid sentences ... that means that the serial communication is good ... the module itself is saying that the data in the sentences is invalid, probably because the lat/lon info is missing ... so the problem is either configuration, or the module hardware on the satellite receiver side

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to print the number of satellites connected to the GPS module?

Comment: Using example sketches give invalid results also haha

Comment: looks like you may want either GGA, or GSA sentence .... https://web.archive.org/web/20200131031033/www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm

Comment: So you say that i need to check those sentences in order to understand if the gps is fixed or not..

Comment: all I am saying is, look at the type of information that can be obtained from these various sentences  .... it is up to you to to decide if the information is useful to you .... personally, i would print out as many different sentences as possible and look at them  .... i would also try to find out if there is a command available that dumps multiple different sentences at once ..... here is a similar web page that is still alive http://aprs.gids.nl/nmea/  ..... note: GSV lists satellites in view